# Is connection tracking a kind of table in iptables?

Tags: iptables

There are four tables and five chains in iptables concept.
All the tables:raw,filter,nat,mangle;and the chains:input,output,forward,prerouting,postrouting.
The diagram below shows the flow of packets through the chains in various tables in detail.
[The diagram below shows the flow of packets through the chains in various tables:](https://www.booleanworld.com/depth-guide-iptables-linux-firewall/)
Let's have a look at `output` chain (same as in `prerouting` chain),it says from right to left that `raw`,`connecting tracking`,`mangle`,`nat`,`filter`,is `connecting tracking` a kind of table?
A conclusion in the webpage says `Each of these tables are composed of a few default chains`,so from this conclusion, i think that `connecting tracking` is a kind of table.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an iptables-"table", but a module making use of the linux kernel functionality of connection tracking, which stores connection information in  `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` and/ or `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`.

Comment: cat  /proc/net/ip_conntrack    
cat: /proc/net/ip_conntrack: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you load the conntrack module? `modprobe nf_conntrack`

Comment: It is `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` ,instead of `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` in my centos7.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, depends on the version.